# 3TB Seagate hard drive shows 249GB free when installed

Tags: windows-7, gpt

my new seagate sata drive keeps showing as a 249gb drive but in the setup part when i press del at the boot up it states there a 3000gb drive and i have searched for a solution but havent found one yet. I havent tried in a different pc yet and I have an asus gaming board with 2 video cards sli'ed and i have windows 7 ultimate 64 bit with 8gb ram and a hp 23" widescreen monitor and the sniper gaming case and a salitek lighted up gaming keyboard and a razor death adder gaming mouse and a corsair 850 watt power supply.

Comment: Did you have a hard drive installed previously, and backed up your system onto the new drive?

Answer (score 2):

MSDOS MBR partition tables can only handle a maximum of 2TB, to use more than this one needs to use another partition table format the only alternative one windows 7 supports is GPT partition tables.

If it is a secondary drive this can just be used, in windows volume manager right click blank drive with no volumes and choose convert to GPT.

However if it is a primary hard disk your motherboard must have an EFI BIOS to be able to boot from it (the bios needs to know how to read the different boot sector format) as is required to have the system partition on (containing C:\Windows).

The rest is just math error.

Comment: oops, corrected, and until you get the partition table right the OS is not going to read it right, if there are still reading the size incorrectly with GPT tables then there is likely a bios or hardware problem reporting something incorrectly.